# Load an Python object from File (Maybe without class definition)

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization

I am a complete newbie to Python.

I have data in the following format :

```
ontology = {


  'OBJECT' :


    {'IS-A' : {'VALUE' :'ALL'},


     'SUBCLASSES' : {'VALUE' :['PHYSICAL-OBJECT',


                               'MENTAL-OBJECT','SOCIAL-OBJECT']},


     'THEME-OF' : {'sem' : 'EVENT'}},





 'PHYSICAL-OBJECT' :


    {'IS-A' : {'VALUE' :'OBJECT'},


     'SUBCLASSES' : {'VALUE' :['ANIMATE', 'INANIMATE']},


     'THEME-OF' : {'sem' : 'EVENT'}},
}
```

I want to load all this data into a Python dictionary. 
But I get an error if I used the eval(file.read()).

Is there any way I can do this? (I don't have any class definitions)

Comment: What error so you get ? You should try ast.literal_eval() .

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 20, in <module>
    getData()
  File "Test.py", line 11, in getData
    dict = eval(file.read())
  File "<string>", line 15
    ontology = {
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eval is generally a bad plan for security reasons, and you'd be better serialising with pickle or JSON.

But it won't read because you can't assign variables with = using eval(). If that's the exact format, you could try skipping after the = and eval()ing the rest:

```
data = open('data.txt').read()
ontology = eval(data[data.find('=')+1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using eval is a really bad idea](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Use [ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) instead.

For that to work, you must get rid of `ontology =` part, it's not needed. Leave only a dictionary itself in a file.

Then, load it as follows:

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open('data.txt') as file:
...     data = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
... 
>>> data
{'PHYSICAL-OBJECT': {'IS-A': {'VALUE': 'OBJECT'}, 'THEME-OF': {'sem': 'EVENT'}, 'SUBCLASSES': {'VALUE': ['ANIMATE', 'INANIMATE']}}, 'OBJECT': {'IS-A': {'VALUE': 'ALL'}, 'THEME-OF': {'sem': 'EVENT'}, 'SUBCLASSES': {'VALUE': ['PHYSICAL-OBJECT', 'MENTAL-OBJECT', 'SOCIAL-OBJECT']}}}
```